# jquery dynamic <tr><td>

Tags: javascript, jquery

My webpage shows a list of 200 products.  The user can use buttons to show and hide products.  I would like to display 2 products per row.  The problem is that the product may need to be on the left or right depending on what products are being shown.

Here is a basic JSFiddle to use as a starting point to explain what I am trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/WABqU/

Comment: So what exactly is the code issue?  What doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably be better off using `<div style="display: inline-block;">` instead of tables. If you set their width to, say, `50px`, and their container to `100px`, this will ensure you get two per line.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.css('visibility', 'hidden')` instead of `.hide()`.